# Batch rename multiple files with appended date and timestamp

Tags: terminal, osx, perl, rename

I need a automatic way of adding a created date and time stamp on all .pdf files within some directory like this; *testfile.pdf* needs to be *testfile-YYY.MM.DD_HH.MM.SS.pdf*
Im using OSX terminal.

I have this code:

```
    cd "/Users/***/Documents/testmapa"
old_filename=""testfile.pdf"
new_filename=${old_filename%.*}$(stat -f %SB -t "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" "$old_filename").${old_filename##*.}
mv "$old_filename" "$new_filename"
```

And this do the job but on one file, how do I apply this on all pdf files in some directory. 
Basically I need a file that will "on click" run some code and add this created date to a file name on all .pdf files that are in directory where the file was clicked. 
And a question, can that code run on subfolders? 
I have perl installed but don't know how to use it. I only know that it has rename function and ctime stat, but I don't know how to write that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this work ok for me:

```
for files in /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/*.sh; do
old_filename=$files
old_filename_stripped=$(basename -a $files)
echo "filename full : $old_filename - file name stripped: $old_filename_stripped"
done
```

output:

```
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/advfind2.sh - file name stripped: advfind2.sh
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/advfind.sh - file name stripped: advfind.sh
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appslist(draft).sh - file name stripped: appslist(draft).sh
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appslist.sh - file name stripped: appslist.sh
```

Improved Code to include spaces and subdirs:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for files in $(find /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/ -name "*.txt" ); do
old_filename="$files"
old_filename_stripped=$(basename -a "$files")
echo "filename full : $old_filename - file name stripped: $old_filename_stripped"
done
unset IFS
```

Output:

```
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/b.txt - file name stripped: b.txt
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/c.txt - file name stripped: c.txt
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/a ver 1.txt - file name stripped: a ver 1.txt
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/d.txt - file name stripped: d.txt
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/a.txt - file name stripped: a.txt
filename full : /home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appsfiles/a.txt - file name stripped: a.txt
```

PS: See the last line, it is a subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for fast replay, but im getting  stat: No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe you have write the directory wrong (or maybe you are using a different shell ? I'm using bash gnu).

Comment: I will update / correct my answer. I will also include the real output from the script.

Comment: Thanks for replay! That actually is working, but looks like file names cannot have spaces in them. I will have to rename them, or is it possible to make it work with spaces. It is working when I remove them from name. Also is it possible to do the same on subfolders?

Comment: Let me know if the improved code that i added in my answer does the job you want. Should handle spaces and subdirs correctly.

Comment: Yes Sir! Sorry for late replay, it does it job with spaces and subfolders. Thank you. I will add that code in my question maybe it will be helpful to someone.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Is not necessary to add the solution in your question. Your question and my answer will remain under this topic, and will be visible to anybody. PS: It is also not necessary to use the old-filename-stripped part in your final code, if you don't make use of the stripped file name.

Comment: OK, thank you for the tips. I'm new here, well long time lurker actually. I have learned a lot from this. But I actually did it wrong from start. I need real  pdf meta info on created date, not file created that is local system info. Now I have to find a way to replace stat -f with exiftool CreateDate and do exactly the same thing. But that is another question all together, thank you for your fast help.